# How to call a method after clicking a fieldset in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

This is the code from my .xhtml file and I added  under the fieldset

**index.xhtml**

```
    <p:fieldset legend="BPS Listener Method" toggleable="true" collapsed="#{bpsFrontBean.bpsListenerSwitch}" toggleSpeed="500" style="width: 920px;margin: 0 auto; text-align: left">
    <p:ajax listener="#{bpsFrontBean.onToggleBpsListenerSwitch}" update="parametersGrid"/>
    .........
    </p:fieldset>
```

if I run the code above before the page is shown, there is an error saying:

```
    javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: <p:ajax> Event attribute could not be determined: null
```

I want to trigger a method if the toggleable fieldset was clicked.

Comment: what version of primefaces are you using?

Comment: posted a reference to the user guide

Comment: thanks sir jack, hi to ASG3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page 205-206 of Primefaces User Guide (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/fieldset.xhtml) says:

> **Ajax Behavior Events**
>
> *toggle* is the default and only ajax behavior
> event provided by fieldset that is processed when the content is
> toggled. In case you have a listener defined, it will be invoked by
> passing an instance of org.primefaces.event.ToggleEvent.
>
> Here is an example that adds a facesmessage and updates growl
> component when fieldset is toggled.

```
<p:growld id="messages" />
<p:fieldset legend="Toggleable Fieldset" toggleable="true">
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.onToggle}" update="messages"/>
    //content
</p:fieldset>
```

On the bean:

```
public void onToggle(ToggleEvent event) {
   Visibility visibility = event.getVisibility();
   FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage();
   msg.setSummary("Fieldset " + event.getId() + " toggled");
   msg.setDetail("Visibility: " + visibility);
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. You didn't close the tags correctly: `<p:fieldset` needs to be closed with `>` and `<p:ajax` should end with `/>`

Comment: How is the xhtml here different in a relevant way to the question? I wonder what part solved the problem of OP that it got accepted as an answer

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `event="toggle"` inside `p:ajax` to get rid of the error:

```
<p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{bpsFrontBean.onToggleBpsListenerSwitch}" update="parametersGrid"/>
```

Unfortunately this is currently (PF 8) not mentioned in the documentation.